# How to change format of date in smart-table

Tags: smart-table

i'm using Smart-Table in my mean.js app, and i need change format of date values. For default format is "MMM, dd yyyy" and I want to change it to "dd-MM-yyyy". Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in angular documentation you can change the format of the angular [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

so your markup cood look like

```
<td>{{myDateValue | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}</td>
```